# Note taking apps on macos that allow drawing (using the iPad pro as another monitor w/ duet (or similar))

Tags: macos, ios, ipad, notes.app, evernote

tldr: I need a whiteboarding/drawing/notes app that will also let me add text using the macbook's keyboard

I have one macbook and one iPad pro. I use the ipad + pencil to sketch ideas and write math formulas. I would also like to type in the same document from the macbook. What app can do this?

I like using Duet to make the iPad function as another macOS screen, but unfortunately the macOS version of evernote doesn't support drawing, only the iOS version lets one draw.

I have tried using the iPad pro as a standalone iOS device, running evernote. Under this setup, the sketching works great, but now when I need to type something with a keyboard, it's a pain to use the iPad's keyboard. I would much rather use the macbook's.

A variation on the theme of using the iPad in iOS, perhaps one could use a different sketching app in iOS that syncs very quickly between macbook and ipad. Evernote and notes both do not have live syncing. Do other iOS drawing/typing apps?

- Is there a drawing/typing app for macOS that supports the Pencil on the iPad?

Or

- Is there a drawing/typing app for iOS that syncs instantly with macOS?

Both Notes and Evernote suffer the problem of not supporting instant sync on the iOS to macOS. Both also suffer the problem of not having a drawing mode on the macOS version.

I don't necessarily need to save the notes. I just need a whiteboarding app. I can copy what I come up with to evernote when the draft is done.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution that came to my mind was Notability. I personally use Notability for taking notes using my iPhone, iPad and MacBook Pro. Notability supports drawings and typing and has nearly instant speed of showing changes across all the connected devices through iCloud.

Also they support Apple Pencil on iPad and will support duet as well. But I'm not sure about that.

If you definitely want something like that just give a try to notability.